# Converting a document to pdf on sever side .NET

Tags: .net, pdf, document

I want to convert a document .doc, .docx or .txt to pdf but i want only the server to fill requierements. What i mean is i don`t want the user to need to have word, adobe reader or anything installed on their machine. I just want a user to upload a document file and the server convert it and store it into pdf. Similar to what scribd does.

Comment: looking for a free or open source posibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way that I've done this is to install a virtual pdf printer on the server, and print the document.

I used [Bullzip PDF](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php). You can create a [runonce.ini](https://sites.google.com/site/bullzip/pdf-printer/documentation/reference/configuration-files) that stores settings for the next print and the printer will silently print the document with whatever name/location/etc. is stored in runonce.

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't seem to be what i was looking for, i just need that a user on his pc uploads a file to my server and my server converting it instantly to pdf, unfortunately the only answer seems to be Aspose or something like that

Comment: @Agorilla: What I've described can do/does do just that. It 'prints' the document to a PDF located wherever you want it to on your server. It is then available for use to do whatever you want with.

Answer (score 0):

What about a control like

[UseOffice.net](http://www.vclcomponents.com/ASP_NET/Development_Tools/UseOffice__Net-info.html)

(Not free)

Comment: thanks, but i was looking for a free or open source ddl, but i`m starting to believe that i would not be possible. if i don`t get an open source anwser i will mark yours as correct.

Comment: I have looked myself before for a free dll and ended up using jpg' instead, so I suspect this still maybe the case.